# Почему для тегов и статей используют 3 таблицы?

Tags: база-данных

Я хочу реализовать сайт со статьями. Сайт с более чем несколькими миллионами статей. У каждой статьи есть от 1 до 100 тегов. На сайте будет активно использоваться поиск по нескольким тегам (Записи имеющие каждый тег из условия)
Как я понимаю, для решения этой проблемы есть два решения:

1. Реализовать 2 таблицы. Таблица с Записями и именованиями Тегов (Имя, Ид). В Таблице записи будут храниться сами записи и для каждой из них будет колонка с массивом Ид тегов.
2. Реализовать 3 таблицы. Таблица с Записями (Только с информацией о записи), именованием Тегов (Имя, Ид) и таблицы Запись_Текст.
   Что лучше? Почему? Ну или может есть другие варианты?

Comment: `колонка с массивом` - это сразу отбросьте. Хотя бы из-за скорости поиска

Comment: Почему? Разве не проще искать вхождение подмассива (Массива из Ид тегов из поиска) в массиве (Ид тегов записи)?

Comment: Как я себе это представляю.  
При выборе тегов делается запрос в бд ко всем записям и идёт поиск вхождения тегов записи в список тегов поиска.  
Во 2 случае мы делаем 1+( колличество категорий в поиске) подзапросов.
1) таблица Записей
2) таблица Запись_Тег для каждого подзапроса.
 
В 1 случае делаем 1 подзапрос. Таблица записей
Но в каждой записей ищем вхождение массива в другой массив
  
Звучит что 1 вариант проще. Но не уверен.